# error while validating form from ini file

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-controller

Hii...

When I tried to validate zend form using ini file, I am getting the following error message, please help how to fix this

```
Uncaught Zend_Config_Exception, code: 0
Message: parse_ini_file(views/config/adminvalidate.ini) [<a href='function.parse-
ini-file'>function.parse-ini-file</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or 
directory
```

Thanks

Comment: double check the permission and make sure the file path is correct

Answer (score 0):

> Message: parse_ini_file(views/config/adminvalidate.ini)

Your config file is in the `views` folder?

**Update**

I usually need to provide an absolute path to the `Zend_Config_Ini` constructor:

`APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/config/adminvalidate.ini'`

Comment: Updated answer with recommendation for absolute path.

Comment: I am able fix it using absolute path...thanx

Comment: Glad it helped. Have you accepted (clicked the check mark) any answers from your questions? Typically, a high "accept-rate" encourages SO users to answer questions.